# Can not find the "fiostream.h" file

Tags: c++, include

I'm learning C++ now.

Here is my question:

```
#include <fiostream.h>
```

No matter I used:

```
#include <fiostream>

#include "fiostream"

#include "fiostream.h"
```

I can not find this "fiostream.h" file anywhere.

Where I can find the "fiostream.h" file?

Does the "iostream.h" include the "fiostream.h"'s functions?

What's difference between "fiostream.h" and "iostream.h"?

Thank you~~

Comment: are you trying fstream perhaps?

Comment: The header doesn’t exist.

Comment: [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header) are the standard headers. `fiostream` isn't one.

Comment: Wow, what made you think it exists? I haven't seen it mentioned in maybe 2 decades

Comment: What are you reading!?!

Comment: You need more modern study materials - something from this millennium.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What's difference between "fiostream.h" and "iostream.h"?

The difference is an “f”. But neither header exists. `iostream` does, `fiostream` doesn’t (but `fstream` does).

Answer (score 1):

`fiostream.h` is not a `std` header.

Try

```
#include <fstream>
```

You can read more about [`std::fstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream) and [`#include <iostream>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/iostream) at [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/).

Answer (score 0):

There is no `<fiostream[.h]>` nor `<iostream.h>` header. The I/O library provides the following C++ standard library headers:

- Forward declarations: `<iosfwd>`
- Standard iostream objects: `<iostream>`
- Iostreams base classes: `<ios>`
- Stream buffers: `<streambuf>`
- Fromatting and manipulators: `<istream>`, `<ostream>`, `<iomanip>`
- String streams: `<sstream>`
- File streams: `<fstream>`, `<cstdio>`.

Note that C++ standard library headers do not end with `.h` - that is only the C library headers. The C++ standard library versions of C library headers begin with the letter `c`. For example, `cstdio` is the C++ version of `stdio.h`.

Answer (score 0):

fiostream is not exists in c++ but iostream.h exists.
Including this header may automatically include other headers, such as ios, streambuf, istream, ostream and/or iosfwd.

The available C++ standard headers are in the link for further studies. [click here for more details](http://www.cpp-home.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=252)